# Trouble installing JGR

Tags: java, macos, r

I have been trying to install JGR with no success.  When I try I get the error posted below.  I have tried using the JGR-1.6-SL.dmg to install as well as through the R terminal.  It seems like a java issue but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is my system info:

```
OSX 10.7.2
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-383, mixed mode)
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)  (Installed with homebrew)
```

Error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘iplots’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Note: On Mac OS X we strongly recommend using iplots from within JGR.
Proceed at your own risk as iplots cannot resolve potential ev.loop deadlocks.
'Yes' is assumed for all dialogs as they cannot be shown without a deadlock,
also ievent.wait() is disabled.
2012-01-29 16:24:57.870 R[29384:c07] Apple AWT Java VM was loaded on first thread -- can't start AWT.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'iplots', details:
  call: .jnew("org/rosuda/iplots/Framework")
  error: java.lang.InternalError: Can't start the AWT because Java was started on the first thread.  Make sure StartOnFirstThread is not specified in your application's Info.plist or on the command line
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/User/Library/R/2.14/library/iplots’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘iplots’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘iplots’ is not available for package ‘JGR’
* removing ‘/Users/User/Library/R/2.14/library/JGR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘JGR’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install R from homebrew R is compiled from source. To install something like iplots where you get this error you need to use the following command from the R console:

```
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)
```

You may need to remove this afterwords in which case you can use this:

```
Sys.unsetenv("NOAWT")
```

Answer (score 3):

On your version of OS X you need to set `NOAWT=1` if you want to compile iplots and JGR packages from sources (e.g. by using `NOAWT=1 R CMD INSTALL ..`).

Please use [stats-rosuda-devel](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) mailing list for questions about JGR/rJava/iplots

Comment: I installed R with homebrew.  I'm not sure how I would specify that with homebrew.

Comment: It doesn't mater what R you use (although using released R would make your life much easier). You simply set the `NOAWT` environment variable - how you do that is entirely up to you, there are many ways - the above is what I use.

Comment: BTW: If you use JGR with anything other than the official binary, you're entirely on your own - you may even need to modify the launcher to match your non-standard setup if it is radically different.